# WAMP Virtual Hosts Not Working

Tags: apache, virtual, wamp, httpd.conf, hosts

please help me, I am pulling my hair out. I cannot get Virtual Hosts to work with WAMP. I have uncommented out this line:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\project\public"
    ServerName project
    ErrorLog "logs/project.localhost.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project.localhost.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong? Where is my error?  Why won't it show my virtual host?

Comment: First reformat your post, second describe exactly what doesn't work for you and last but not least that's a question for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I forgot to add the host names in the Windows host file.

Comment: please add steps which u followed.

Comment: This is 1 line entry as
ipaddress        hostname
127.0.0.1        www.example.com
This is just an example. you need to replace ip address and host name that you have.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your hosts file on the server. This will map the virtual host name to an IP address. To keep this simple, we'll map 127.0.0.1 to mysite. Here's how:

1. Open Notepad as the administrator.
2. Open the file C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.
3. Add the line: 127.0.0.1 mysite.
4. Save the host file (making sure to not save it as a .txt
   file).